# Loading GIF Icon when Page is Busy

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

How would I make a loading GIF icon appear every time the page is busy like on click events and data are loaded from the database?

I don't want the icon to appear on the page load.

Comment: I tried doing it manually.

I have a div that appears every time the page is busy on click and then I hide it after the process. It works fine.

But I got a mission to add a loading GIF image. I add it on the div during on click and remove it before an alert appear.

The problem is we use an ajax that has "getErrMsg" function. I have to add if statement in that function because not all error has to remove the GIF image. Also, I don't know all the error message that I should include in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that Eclipse can't debug server side scripting language but your browser can. I am using Google Canary now.